# Integration by parts of a function

Tags: integration

I have the following function to integrate by parts can't go around that on this assignment, i can't figure out what is the f and g and their derivatives respectively.

$$
∫x^3e^{-x^2}dx
$$

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: Hint: pick $u=x^2$ and $dv=xe^{-x^2}\,dx$ where $\int u\,dv=uv-\int v\,du$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

Exponentials of functions are quite often impossible to integrate, unless multipied by the derivative of the function to form an expression like

$$f'(x)e^{f(x)}.$$

When you see such an expression, jump on it !

Here you observe

$$x^3e^{-x^2}=-\frac{x^2}2(-x^2)'e^{-x^2}.$$

The rest is yours.

Answer (score 0):

$$u=x^2, dv=xe^{-x^2}dx, v=-\frac{1}{2}e^{-x^2}, du=2xdx$$

so

$$\int x^3e^{-x^2}dx=-\frac{1}{2}x^2e^{-x^2}+\int xe^{-x^2}dx$$

where the new integral can be easily calculated by substitution $u=x^2$.

Comment: Thanks a lot, and wow that was fast, this forum is awesome, shame i didnt find it sooner!

Comment: @JorgeFilipe You are very welcome! (Sadly, lots of people choose to use this forum to let the community solve their homework for them...)

Comment: My problem was i understand this topic i just blocked on this function dunno why, anyways again thank you!

Comment: @JorgeFilipe, Sure, that is what this forum *is* for - try to get people unstuck when they are genuinely stuck, and exchange various ideas on the way. Pleased to help.

Answer (score 0):

**hint**

Put $$u (x)=-\frac {x^2}{2}$$
and
$$v'(x)=-2xe^{-x^2} $$

thus
$$u'(x)=-x $$
and
$$v (x)=e^{-x^2} $$

it becomes
$$\Bigl [u (x)v(x)\Bigr]+\int xe^{-x^2}dx $$

$$=u (x)v (x)-\frac{1}{2}v (x) $$
$$=-\frac {x^2+1}{2}e^{-x^2} +C $$